# How to set NTFS permissions to specific folders in a folder structure?

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way, where i run a script using powersell, that goes through a folder structure and set certain NTFS permissions only to a folder with a name "Submissions", so if there is any folder called "Submissions" within the folder structure, it will set it to NTFS permissions that i specified..

Any info will help me to start this!

http://s22.postimg.org/r769bcr01/Capture.png

Lets say i have this many folders, and in each folder, the structure is the same:

http://s15.postimg.org/pqh8leph7/sasa.png

So i need to aim at 04_architecture for example, and apply certain NTFS permissions, using powershell.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` and `Set-ACL` in PowerShell. This is a very broad question. SO is not really a place to use _as a starting point_.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a starting point:

```
# find all submissions directories
$submissions = Get-ChildItem -Path "YOUR START PATH e.g. c:\test" -Recurse -Filter "Submissions" -directory
foreach($submission in $submissions)
{
    # get the current submission directory acl
    $acl = Get-ACL $submission.FullName

    # create a new acl. Example:
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('Administrators','FullControl','ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')

    # add and set the new created acl to the directory
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    Set-Acl $submission.FullName $acl
}
```